# CAS Maxima: problem with relational operator in function definition

Tags: maxima

In CAS Maxima, I defined the Tent Map as follows:

```
<code>
    TMm2(x):=2*if x>1/2 then 1-x else x
</code>
```

Starting with

```
<code>
   TM:1/%pi
</code>
```

and then iterating according to

```
 <code>
  for i:0 thru 60 do 
    (
      TMC1oPI:coeff(TM,1/%pi,1), TMCconst:coeff(TM,1/%pi,0),
      TMstr:sconcat(i,";",TMC1oPI,";",TMCconst),
      print(TMstr),
      TM:(expand(TMm2(TM))), 
      if TM = 0 then return("Iterating the Tent Map ended at its fixed point zero!")
    )
  </code>
```

the output begins to fail in the line starting with 56

```
<code>
   55;-36028797018963968;11468322278445318
   56;-72057594037927936;22936644556890636
   57;-144115188075855872;45873289113781272
   58;-288230376151711744;91746578227562544
   59;-576460752303423488;183493156455125088
   60;-1152921504606846976;366986312910250176
</code>
```

The problem is that the relational operator evaluates to false when applied to the results in the line starting with 55, though the accurate result of that line is

```
<code>-36028797018963968/%pi+11468322278445318</code>
```

which is about `0.71`, so that the next result should be about `0.58`, but

```
<code>-72057594037927936/%pi+22936644556890636</code>
```

evaluates to about `1.42`, which is an error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the code to determine the sign of an expression. In this case it is incorrectly saying that `x > 1/2` is false for x equal to `11468322278445318 - 36028797018963968/%pi`. As a workaround, try setting `fpprec` to a large value, say 100, and then replacing `if x > 1/2 then ...` with `if bfloat(x) > 1/2 then ...`. I know this is not very good.

Comment: I made a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/4106/

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Mr. Dodier. //  Meanwhile, I have re-written the function in order to operate on the two integer factors TMC1oPI and TMCconst separately. It now adjusts the value of fpprec according to the magnitude of these factors before calculating the function value needed for branching. For n = 16384, both factors have about 5k decimal figures... but Maxima can handle that.